# How to replace missing values for certain rows

Tags: stata

I'm wondering how to replace missing values in Stata for certain rows only (as noted above).

I have a long column with 842 cells. The first 160 should be 1, and the rest should be 0. However, I have missing values scattered throughout 1-842. How can I replace the missing values in 1:160 with 1, and the missing values in 161:842 with 0?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which rows? How will you identify them? What have you tried? What do you want to replace them with?

Comment: Hi Stuart! I Have a long column with 842 cells. The first 160 should be 1, and the rest should be 0. However, I have missing values scattered throughout 1-842. How can I replace the missing values in 1:160 with 1, and the missing values in 161:842 with 0?

Comment: To Stata programmers, rows are observations and columns are variables. Stern conventions here to focus on the technical question and answer are friendlier than they may seem: everyone benefits long-term from avoidance of personal comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replace myvar = cond(_n <= 160, 1, 0) if missing(myvar)
```